# Creating a date with 1st, 2nd or 3rd day of the week in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to determine what day of the week a given number is,

For E.g. I have Year = 2018 Calendar Week = 51 and Number = 3 (This is 3rd day of the week)

Calendar week 51 falls in the month of December

Week starts from Monday to Sunday

Since 3rd day in week 51 is 19th, the result should be **"19/12/2018"**.

Could we do it excel formula or VBA macro.

Any help in this regard deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Blatantly copying from [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/04/29/excel-weeknum-function-convert-week-number-date/) you can use an Excel formula:

```
=DATE(<YearNumber>, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(<YearNumber>, 1, 3)) + <WeekNumber> * 7+ <DayNumber> -1
```

So `=DATE(2018, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(2018, 1, 3)) + 51 * 7 + 3 - 1` returns *19 December 2018*.

Comment: This is great! its working.... However instead manually typing Year Number, weekNumber and DayNumber. I did cell reference, Year and week number are working fine but however if I change daynumber in the cell the result is not changing.Here is the formula I used where Year in Cell F3, week in G3 and Day in H3=DATE(F3, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(F3, 1, H3)) + G3 * 7+ H3-1

Comment: Your first reference to day should be just the number 3: `=DATE(F3, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(F3, 1, 3)) + G3 * 7+ (H3-1)`

Answer (score 0):

It is obtained by vba. One is a macro and one is udf.

Macro

```
Sub getWeekDays()
    Dim vDB, vS(), vR()
    Dim y As Integer, s As Date, e As Date
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    'y = Year
    y = InputBox("Input year : 2018  ")

    s = DateSerial(y, 1, 0)
    e = DateSerial(y + 1, 1, 0)
    n = e - s
    For i = 1 To n
        d = s + i
        If DatePart("ww", d, vbMonday) = DatePart("ww", d + 1, vbMonday) Then
        Else
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 2, 1 To k)
            vR(1, k) = DatePart("ww", d, vbMonday) & " Wk"
            If k = 1 Then
                vR(1, k) = DatePart("ww", s + 1, vbMonday) & " Wk"
                vR(2, k) = Format(s + 1, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "~" & Format(d, "dd.mm.yyyy")
            Else
                vR(2, k) = Format(d - 6, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "~" & Format(d, "dd.mm.yyyy")
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    Range("a1").Resize(k, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

UDF

```
Function getWeekDay(y As Integer, WeekNum As Integer, DayOrder As Integer)
    Dim s As Date, e As Date
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    'WeekNum = 51
    'y = Year
    'DayOrder <~~ If third day  DayOrder = 3

    s = DateSerial(y, 1, 0)
    e = DateSerial(y + 1, 1, 0)
    n = e - s
    For i = 1 To n
        d = s + i

        If DatePart("ww", d, vbMonday) = WeekNum Then
            getWeekDay = d + DayOrder - 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]