# Get day number within calendar week for a specific date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set which includes dates. 
I need to split this out by week number for reporting purposes. 
What I have so far is:

startDate variable containing 03/01/2015 (populated from data in spreadsheet)

```
startDay = Day(startDate)
startMonth = Month(startDate)
startYear = Year(startDate)

startWeek = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DateSerial(startYear, startMonth, startDay))
```

which gives me week 1 in startWeek

However I know need to know how far into week 1 the date is.
So for this example, as the date is the 3rd of January, it includes 3 days of week 1

Meaning the reporting I'm putting together will only report on 3 days (as opposed to the full week)

The only way I've figured to do this so far is to calculate which day of the year the date is and the use a MOD calculation (basically divide by 7 and the remainder is how far into the week it is)

```
dayNumber = DateDiff("d", DateSerial(startYear, 1, 1), DateSerial(startYear, startMonth, startDay)) + 1 

dayOfWeek = dayNumber Mod 7
```

This does work, but I was wondering if there was a nicer solution than this.

Comment: Using your `startWeek` equation makes 7th January the 1st day of Week 2, not the 7th day of week 1.  You also say that 3rd January is Day 3 of Week 1.  This means that either **A)** Week 1 is only 6 days long, or **B)** 3rd January is actually the *4th* day of Week 1, and the 1st day is the 31st December - please can you clarify?

Comment: @Chronocidal note that he is talking about 2015 but you refer to 2018. That's confusing because that changes everything

Comment: @OP:  Just to clarify things up, could you please post a table of expected output for the 1st January until the 14th January for **2015** and (ideally, if possible) **2018**

Comment: So basically 1st to 7th January will be week 1 (days 1 to 7)
8th to 14th will be week 2 (days 1 to 7)
etc

Comment: @MichaelLiew Note that if you assume *1st to 7th January will be week 1 (days 1 to 7)* you cannot use `WorksheetFunction.WeekNum` because this will give you a **different** result (see the table in my answer where using `weeknum` the first week has only 6 days)!

Comment: refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649879/creating-a-date-with-1st-2nd-or-3rd-day-of-the-week-in-excel/53662751#53662751)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop to determine how many days before `startDate` the week number changed:

```
Public Sub FindDaysInWeekNo()
    Dim startDate As Date
    startDate = DateSerial(2015, 1, 3)

    Dim startWeek As Integer
    startWeek = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(startDate)

    Dim i As Integer
    Do While startWeek = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DateAdd("d", -i, startDate))
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Debug.Print i '= 3rd day in this week number
End Sub
```

The following table shows my comparison to the other suggested formulas and why I think that (refered to `=WEEKNUM`) my calculation is correct.

[image]

**Note that if you assume *1st to 7th January will be week 1 (days 1 to 7)* you cannot use the `WeekNum` function because this will give you a different result (see table above and note that the first week has only 6 days according to the `WeekNum` function).** Also you cannot name this week number (as what everybody calls *week number* is defined as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering).

Instead you will need to use …

```
Public Function AlternativeWeekNum(startDate As Date) As Integer
    AlternativeWeekNum = WorksheetFunction.Days(startDate, DateSerial(Year(startDate), 1, 1)) \ 7 + 1 'note that this no normal division but a integer division and uses a backslash instead
End Function
```

to calculate the week number your alternative way, and …

```
Public Function AlternativeWeekNumDay(startDate As Date) As Integer
    AlternativeWeekNumDay = WorksheetFunction.Days(startDate, DateSerial(Year(startDate), 1, 1)) Mod 7 + 1
End Function
```

to calculate the day in the alternative week.

Comment: This is functionally identical to `Weekday(startDate,vbSunday)`

Comment: @Chronocidal no it is not! See my comparison sheet! Where my function shows the correct numbering refered to the `weeknum` function but all others don't.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at there: apologies

Comment: @Chronocidal The problem here actually is that week numbering is not continuous at the end of the year but weekdays are.

Comment: I have noticed though:  Your formula doesn't give the same results as OPs `dayOfWeek = dayNumber Mod 7` one, but mine (almost - I output 7 where OP outputs 0) does.  Still clarification required >_<'

Comment: @Chronocidal yes, true. I assume that he also didn't realize about how fancy week numbers are actually calculated and that they don't start on Jan. 1st every year and count to 7 … . Actually it becomes more complicated if you take account of how different countries calculate the week numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering

Comment: interesting, thanks for that.
What I'm working on goes on the assumption that week 1 starts on 1st Jan each year

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Weekday()` function for this:

```
=WEEKDAY(B4;2)
```

The second parameter mentions how you want your days to be counted (starting from Sunday or Monday, counting starting from 0 or from 1, ...).

Comment: This will not work because it does not take account of week numbering that starts on a different day every year!

Comment: To expand on this and address the issue raised by @Pᴇʜ : the second argument of `WEEKDAY` will accept several values - `2` will give `1 - Monday` through `7 - Sunday`.  However, `11` through `17` form an interesting pattern - `11` is the same as `2`, but `12` gives `1 - Tuesday` through `7 - Monday`, `13` will make `1 - Wednesday`, etc.  `10+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1), 2)` will give you the right second argument to get the day (1-7) of the week starting on the same day as 1st January.  The full equation being `=WEEKDAY(A1,10+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1),2))`

Comment: @Chronocidal must be something wrong. Test `2018-01-07` in your formula. It's the first day in week number 2 but your formula says 7 days?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The first day of week 2 is always the  8th January, as the 1st day of week 1 is always the 1st January (not the 31st December)

Comment: @Chronocidal no please refer how weeknumbers are calculated!`=WEEKNUM()` of `2018-01-07` is `2`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Urgh...  You're right.  That contradicts *"So for this example, as the date is the 3rd of January, it includes 3 days of week 1"*, since it would make it Day 4.  I'll drop a comment on the Question to request clarification

Answer (score -1):

```
dayOfWeek  = (8 + Weekday(startDate) - Weekday(DateSerial(startYear, 1, 1))) mod 7
```

Just take the positive `mod 7` of the difference between the current Day-Of-Week and the Day-Of-Week for the 1st January of whatever the year is

Comment: there is a parenthesis missing, and it is calculating wrong! test `2018-01-07` where `=Weeknum(2018-01-07)` says `2`  but your formula says `7` but it should say `1`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Added the parenthesis, and also added a request-for-clarification to the Question since I was matching against the line *"So for this example, as the date is the 3rd of January, it includes 3 days of week 1"*, which would make 7th January the 7th day of Week 1

Comment: but `2015-01-03` actually **is** the 3rd day of week number (`=WEEKNUM`) 1  while `2018-01-07` is week number 2 (first day) if we refer to the `weeknum` function. Since he is using the `weeknum` function there is no other interpretation about when weeknumbers start and end.